# How do I stack two containers when they're in different components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In my React app I am creating a task tracker and I have a form which is used to add or filter tasks in one component. In another component I am mapping through the tasks the list each task. I'm trying to put my task list on top of the form container.

TaskList.js

```
function TaskList({ tasks, setTasks, filterTasks }) {
  return (
    <div className='task-container'>
      <ul className='task-list'>
        {filterTasks.map((task) => (
          <Task
            task={task}
            tasks={tasks}
            setTasks={setTasks}
            text={task.text}
            id={task.id}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TaskForm.js

```
return (
    <div className='form-container'>
      <form className='task-form'>
        <input
          value={inputText}
          onChange={inputHandler}
          type='text'
          className='task-input'
        />
        <button onClick={submitHandler} className='task-button' type='submit'>
          <i className='fas fa-plus-square'></i>
        </button>
        <div className='select'>
          <select onChange={statusHandler} name='tasks' className='filter-task'>
            <option value='all'>All</option>
            <option value='completed'>Completed</option>
            <option value='uncompleted'>Uncompleted</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Styles

```
.form-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.task-form {
  background-color: #222831;
  width: 450px;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

form input,
form button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
form button {
  color: #ff6f47;
  background: #f7fffe;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
form button:hover {
  background: #ff6f47;
  color: white;
}

.task-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.task-list {
  min-width: 30%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.task {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.task-button {
  margin: 0;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.filter-task {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.task li {
  flex: 1;
}

.task-item {
  padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
}

.task-input {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

When changing the positioning to absolute, everything shifts to the left. I'm not sure how to make `.task-container` a child element of the `.task-form`.

Comment: You can add TaskList and TaskForm in a parent (page component)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but to answer this part

> "I'm trying to put my task list on top of the form container."

You should just be able to stack the components in whatever parent component you are rendering them in.

Hope this helps, not sure if it answers what you were asking.

```js
function TaskList({}) {
    return (
        <div className='task-container'>
            task list content
        </div>
    );
}

function TaskForm({}) {
    return (
        <div className='form-container'>
            task form content
        </div>
    );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {title} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <TaskList/>
        <TaskForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.task-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="react"></div>
```